# What JavaScript RegEx allows alphanumeric characters except some special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript regular expression that **allows all alphanumeric characters and rejects "&" (ampersand), ";" (semicolon), and " ' " (apostrophe)**.

I know how to allow only certain characters, such as `^[a-zA-Z0-9 @$]*$`—this allows all alphanumeric characters, spaces, "@" (at-sign), and "$" (dollar-sign).

How could I tell it to allow all special characters except **"&", ";" and " ' "**, while allowing all alphanumeric ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole purpose is to allow everything *except* for the `&`, `;`, and `'` symbols, you could just ignore those:

```
[^&;']*
```

This should allow all alpha-numeric symbols and every other special character.

If your list of acceptable/rejected characters is more complicated, it may be easier to write a regex specifying what's *allowed*, like your original sample of `^[a-zA-Z0-9 @$]*$`. It all depends on what your needs are and/or if they'll change (I, personally, would prefer your original regex if it's not going to change much).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Yes I want to reject only few say five special character. but how would I ignore? I need to display error message that your entry contain invalid chanters.

Comment: To define a pattern to ignore a certain character-set, you would use `[^`*characters to ignore*`]`. In my answer, the pattern `[^&;']*` is set to return every character that *doesn't* match the specified ones. If you have only five you want to ignore, put all five in that list and you should be good.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't the `'` need to be escaped, even in a `[ ]` set?

Comment: @Nick No, you shouldn't have to escape the quote (even outside of the brackets). Unless your regex is *inside* single quotes of course =P

Answer (score 1):

The format `[^ ]` is the opposite of `[ ]`.  So to do what you want, try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 @$]*|[^&;\`]*
```

Comment: thanks Nick, I test your express here with string "test&", it suppose to reject my entry, but not : http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: It rejected the `&` but kept `test` when I checked it at your link.

Comment: thanks Nick, you both give me answer, but i was only able to pick one post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

/^[a-zA-Z0-9 @$]*|[^&;`,"'%!.()]*$/